# getElementsByTagName("td")[col].innerHTML return undefined in ff

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorttable.js

I use a script to make a Sortable Table in my project, the link of demo :

http://www.pascarello.com/sortTable/

but when I integrate this script in my project I get the following error :

```
TypeError: b.getElementsByTagName(...)[col] is undefined

var bCell = b.getElementsByTagName("td")[col].innerHTML;
```

And the code :

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="javascript/sortTable.js"></script>
 <LINK href="css/sortTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 var t1 = new sortableTable("t1",0,"int,str,float,date");
    window.onload = function(){
    t1.init();
  }

 ... 

 <table id="t1"....
 ....
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: done any basic debugging yourself? Checked if the `gEBTN()` call returns anything? Is `col` set? Are there enough `<td>` tags to cover whatever value col has? e.g. if you have 5 tds and you try for col=6, you'll get undefined as well.

Comment: What is `col`? `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of elements (accessible like arrays) and you're trying to access nth element in that array which is not present.

Comment: shouldn't be t1.getElement... ? (not b.getElement) try to see what's in typeof (b)

Comment: Do you have a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in your table? You should.

Comment: Wow, talk about a blast from the past....I have not seen that code in ages.

Comment: ^^ Must be the creator :P

Comment: @MarcB yes I have a correct table code with thead and tbody and the same number of col...

Comment: @i100 it's a standard code in sortTable.js,you should see the code then answer me correctly thanks.

Comment: @NII You should probably show the table's markup.

Comment: As-posted, your JS code is appearing inside of a LINK element (your stylesheet link doesn't have a closing tag and it's not written as an empty element), rather than a SCRIPT element. If that's not the case, you might want to clear up your posted code.

Comment: Either you do not have a thead/tbody sections or there are too many columns in the `int,str,float,date`. FYI, that code is 8 years old and was hacked up quickly for a friend. ;)